# How to use ajax to across domain?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dns

I post my code here.(I add the jquery into my web page)

```
var dataString ='username='+ username + '&password=' + password; 
//alert (dataString);return false; 

$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "http://hisencha.sinaapp.com/login.php", 
        data: dataString, 
        success: function(data) { 

          if(data=='success'){
            window.location.href='list.html';
          }
          else{
            alert(data);
          };
        } 
      });
```

above is part of javascript

here is php(demo)

```
<?php
if ($_POST['username']=='aaa' && $_POST['password']=='aaa')
{
  echo 'success';
}
else
{
  echo 'error';
}
?>
```

What can I do now?And how to fix the error about acrossing domain.

Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use JSONP to do it. Here's some sample jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({ 
     type: "POST", 
     url: "http://hisencha.sinaapp.com/login.php?callback=?", 
     data: dataString,
      dataType: 'JSONP',
     success: function(data) { 

       if(data=='success'){
         window.location.href='list.html';
       }
       else{
         alert(data);
       };
     } 
   });
```

And PHP:

```
<?php
$response = array(
     'something' => 'something'
);
echo $_GET[['callback'].'('.json_encode($response).')';
?>
```

Comment: This answer helped me.Thank you very much.It made me know php more!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to use ajax across domains. It's blocked for security reasons.

Comment: There are ways if the other domain simply sets a header to allow it...https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with JSONP. an [example](http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many example to do it, with [AJAX-CROSS-DOMAIN](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/) or [Proxy Handle](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html).